# Panda add columns with a condition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I use panda in the processing of a table and I am looking to add 2 columns using the column `CardCode` with one condition. I have a user table with 3 columns `CardCode / Id_customer / Id_group` and I would like to add 2 columns in my first array `(customer_id and group_id)` according to the `CardCode`.

Here is my first table (csv file)

```
       CardCode   ItemCode        ItemCodeP  Amount       Price Currency   Discount  ListNum         

    FromDate               ToDate     Type   ReducType                           KeyItem
0      C8500165     BTHC48           BTHC48       1   65,000000      EUR    ,000000        2  2018-10-18 00:00:00  2050-12-31 00:00:00     SPP2      amount              BTHC48_C8500165_SPP2
1      C8500165     BTHC48           BTHC48       5   59,000000      EUR    ,000000        2  2018-10-18 00:00:00  2050-12-31 00:00:00     SPP2      amount              BTHC48_C8500165_SPP2
2      C8500165     BTHC48           BTHC48      10   49,000000      EUR    ,000000        2  2018-10-18 00:00:00  2050-12-31 00:00:00     SPP2      amount              BTHC48_C8500165_SPP2
3      C1400164     BTHC48           BTHC48       1   65,000000      EUR    ,000000        2  2018-10-18 00:00:00  2050-12-31 00:00:00     SPP2      amount              BTHC48_C1400164_SPP2
4      C1400164     BTHC48           BTHC48       5   59,000000      EUR    ,000000        2  2018-10-18 00:00:00  2050-12-31 00:00:00     SPP2      amount              BTHC48_C1400164_SPP2
...         ...        ...              ...     ...         ...      ...        ...      ...                  ...                  ...      ...         ...                               ...
99994  C9204154     369398           369398       1  445,980000      EUR  30,000000        2  1980-01-01 00:00:00  2050-12-31 00:00:00  OEDG-52  percentage           369398_C9204154_OEDG-52
99995  C7300423   69031190         69031190       1   77,220000      EUR  20,000000        2  1980-01-01 00:00:00  2050-12-31 00:00:00  OEDG-52  percentage         69031190_C7300423_OEDG-52
99996  C3800239   50001160         50001160       1   -1,000000      EUR  40,000000        0  1980-01-01 00:00:00  2050-12-31 00:00:00  OEDG-52  percentage         50001160_C3800239_OEDG-52
99997  C0200028  000008309  000008309_I0450       1  779,440000      EUR  20,000000        2  1980-01-01 00:00:00  2050-12-31 00:00:00  OEDG-52  percentage  000008309_I0450_C0200028_OEDG-52
99998  C0700024  000008309  000008309_I1000       1  779,440000      EUR  40,000000        2  1980-01-01 00:00:00  2050-12-31 00:00:00  OEDG-52  percentage  000008309_I1000_C0700024_OEDG-52
```

My array customers:

```
             0     1   2
0     C6710024     1  10
1     C0100003     7  10
2     C0100008     8  10
3     C0100048     9  10
4     C0100078    11  10
...        ...   ...  ..
1899  C4400373  2798  10
1900  C7800620  2801  10
1901  C6303124  2802  10
1902  C4600023  2808  10
1903  C0600345  2811  10
```

Warning there are several identical CardCodes on the first board.

Thank you for help.

Comment: Sounds to me like you are trying to join two dataframes, have a look [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html)

Answer (score 0):

If i got the question right, You want to add two new columns(customer_id and group_id) to the 'My array customer' base on their 'CardCod ' value in your csv file?

Comment: I have a CSV file with CardCode and I ask for a SQL query that retrieves users with 3 columns CardCorde / id_customer / id_group and I would like to add 2 columns at the end of my table that is output from the CSV file id_customer and id_group based CardCode